# mysqli search with while loop output only returns one record

Tags: php, mysqli

Just learning PHP and running in to an issue with outputting multiple values in the search results.

Have multiple transactions in a database with same last name, would like user to input the last name in to search box and get all occurences, current structure only gives me one.  Appreacite your help. Thank you

Have the following SQL query in functions:

```
function search_transactions_ln($x){
    global $connection;

    $query  = "SELECT ALL * ";
    $query .= "FROM transactions ";
    $query .= "WHERE last_name = '{$x}' ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 50";
    $a3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($a3);
    while ($a4 = mysqli_fetch_array ($a3)) {
        return $a4;
    }
}
```

Using the following code to retrieve the result, including the $_POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $last_name = $_POST["ln"];
    $found_transaction = search_transactions_ln($last_name);

    if ($found_transaction) {
        print $found_transaction["last_name"]; **==>>> this produces one result, want to see multiple**
    } else {
        // Failure
        $_SESSION ["message"] = "Last name not found.
    }                  
}
```

Comment: you really should avoid use of global variables .. it's a bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        function search_transactions_ln($x){
            global $connection;

            $query  = "SELECT ALL * ";
            $query .= "FROM transactions ";
            $query .= "WHERE last_name = '{$x}' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 50";
            $a3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            confirm_query($a3);
            $ans =array();
            while ($a4 = mysqli_fetch_array ($a3)) {
              $ans[] = $a4;
            }
           return $ans;
       }
```

**in your calling php file:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $last_name = $_POST["ln"];

    $found_transaction_array = search_transactions_ln($last_name);

   foreach($found_transaction_array as $a){

      // do your task
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You return only the first result from your function:

```
while ($a4 = mysqli_fetch_array ($a3)) {
   return $a4;
}
```

Change it to something like:

```
return $a3;
```

You should also use prepared statements instead of injecting variables directly into your query as you have an sql injection problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning only one string instead of all the results.

If you want to print all of them you have to collect them first into an array and return the array.

You may want to change your function:

```
function search_transactions_ln($x){
    global $connection;

    $query  = "SELECT ALL * ";
    $query .= "FROM transactions ";
    $query .= "WHERE last_name = '{$x}' ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 50";
    $a3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($a3);

    $results = array();
    while ($a4 = mysqli_fetch_array ($a3)) {
      $results[] = $a4;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

You have to also change the the printing to print all the results.